# Seeing the actual error behind 'An unexpected error has occurred' in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In MOSS 2007, we could update the   tag's callstack attribute to true and then customerrors mode to "Off" to see the actual error behind the 'An unexpected error has occurred' message. Does it apply on SharePoint 2010 as well ? I tried it but I get the following error:

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root direc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ULS logs. There is even a nice viewer for it too: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer.

Comment: ULS Viewer is a great tool and helps troubleshoot SharePoint issues pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In web.config change CustomErrors to Off and callstack to "true" (just search for these values)

Comment: actually this is what I did ... please read my question completely

Comment: If the error is in one of the Layouts pages, do the same to the web.config located under 14/template/layouts

Comment: @ria - if you had actually been clear in your question it may have helped us read it completely!!!

Comment: @Vladi: thank u so much ... ill just try and then let u know if it worked.
@Ryan: thanks for ur comment, but actually I have received answers on this question that means that I was not totally unclear in explaining my query :) anyways thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Vladi: Doing the same in TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS web.config didnt help either. Also note that this web.config didnt have the CallStack attribute as the whole <SharePoint> <SafeControl .. tag was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see the error in event viewer's Application logs.

Answer (score 1):

It is still possible to make changes to the web.config to get the regular asp.net yellow screen errors. Much like it is with a standard application, the first time you hit F5 in your SharePoint 2010 project, Visual Studio 2010 will prompt you if you want it to automatically configure the local web.config file for you.

However, in SharePoint 2010, the custom error page displays a GUID which can be used as a bookmark in the Log file. It makes searching the Log file ***much*** easier. But that GUID will not be displayed on the yellow screen error page, so you might want to take that into consideration before modifying the web.config.